# How to detect when child process's spawned child process exits?

Tags: node.js

I spawn a child process using NodeJS and this child process (C++ application) spawns another child process then it exits.

Is there a way to tell NodeJS about this latest spawned child process and capture it's events?

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function start_app() {
    let app_process = spawn("./app", {
        cwd: "/home/proj",
        detached: true
    })

    console.log(`PID Value is ${app_process.pid}`)

    app_process.on("close", function(event) {
        console.log(`On Close
        Event Value:   ${event}
        `)
    });
}

start_app();
```